# Mockito breaking builds on Android >=5.0 but not Android 4.4

Tags: java, android, mockito, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

So I have a test suite that runs fine against Android 4.4.4.  However, when I test against Android 5.0.0 or Android 6.0.0 Mockito starts giving me a series of different problems.  I am using Mockito `v1.9.5` but have tried `1.10.19` and `2.0.49-beta` with the same errors. For example I have the following in my setup code:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

...

MyClass myClass = mock(myClass.class);
when(myClass.myMethod()).thenReturn(5L);
```

And the class method looks something like

```
class MyClass {
    private long myPrivateVariable;

    synchronized long myMethod() {
        return myPrivateVariable
    }
}
```

On Android 4.4.4 this works fine but on Android 5.0.0 I get the following errors:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
3. the parent of the mocked class is not public.
It is a limitation of the mock engine.
```

Another example is in one case I'm mocking a class and calling a method

```
AnotherClass anotherClass = mock(AnotherClass.class)
```

However, when a method of that class is called it raises a `NullPointerException` because a private attribute on that class is not set and a public method requires it.

```
class AnotherClass {
    private PrivateAttribute privateAttribute;

    synchronized Map<String, Object> getAttribute(SomeClass instance) {
        return privateAttribute.getSomething(instance);
    }
}
```

This raises a `NullPointerException` in Android 5.0.0 and Android 6.0.0 but not Android 4.4.4

Comment: This looks like the kind of thing that can happen when a method becomes `final` that wasn't before. Can you confirm that `MyClass` and `AnotherClass` are treated as mocks, not spies, and that neither of your classes (or any parent classes you omitted from the code above) have final modifiers on the relevant methods or the classes themselves?

Comment: @jeff-bowman In the first example, the MyClass instance gets passed to a constructor where it becomes final. However, that happens after this point in the code. The second doesn't appear to have any relation to final attributes. They are also mocks and not spies.  Why would final break in 5.0.0 and not 4.4.4?

Comment: One hazard with Mockito is that it's implemented on proxy subclasses, effectively overriding every method. If your class subclassed any of the Android infrastructure, AND if a method in the parent class became final, then suddenly Java would not call Mockito's override method at the proper time. In other cases, this has caused exceptions similar to yours, which is why I'm asking. **NOTE HOWEVER** that a final class is very different than a final field, so by "final class" I only mean a class with a `final` modifier. A `final` field is unrelated; it just behaves similar to a `const`.